# Exception : submitTopology failed: out of sequence response

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, apache-storm

I run some java code, it wil upload the : storm-starter-topologies-0.9.6.jar
from the examples, console shows:

> 535  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Uploading topology jar C:\apachestorm096\examples\storm-starter\storm-starter-topologies-0.9.6.jar to assigned location: ¨/usr/local/storm/data¨/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-8b5acdaf-e6ce-4b01-9ea9-9bd92e30f417.jar
>
> 1066 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: ¨/usr/local/storm/data¨/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-8b5acdaf-e6ce-4b01-9ea9-9bd92e30f417.jar

But I also get an **error**:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift7.TApplicationException: submitTopology failed: out of sequence response

In the storm UI shows the submitted topology...
But nothing is happening, no streams, no spout, no bolt... no workers...
Eclipse runs locally and storm+zookeeper on a virtual machine.

this is the code :

```
  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
  Config conf = new Config();
  conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "100.0.0.26");
  conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, "2181");

  conf.setNumWorkers(20);
  conf.setMaxSpoutPending(5000);
  
  StormSubmitter submitter = new StormSubmitter();
  conf.setDebug(true);
  Map storm_conf = Utils.readStormConfig();
  storm_conf.put("nimbus.host", "100.0.0.26");
  Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(storm_conf).getClient();
  try {
      NimbusClient nimbus = new NimbusClient(storm_conf, "100.0.0.26", 6627);
  
  
  //submitter.submitTopology("blub", conf, builder.createTopology());
  
  String inputJar = "C:\\apachestorm096\\examples\\storm-starter\\storm-starter-topologies-0.9.6.jar";
  // upload topology jar to Cluster using StormSubmitter
 String uploadedJarLocation = StormSubmitter.submitJar(storm_conf,inputJar);
 
 System.out.println("Try ... ");
 try {
     
      String jsonConf = JSONValue.toJSONString(storm_conf);
      System.out.println("Config : " + jsonConf );
      
      nimbus.getClient().send_getNimbusConf();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      System.out.println("Out of sleep ... ");
      nimbus.getClient().submitTopology("word-count", uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, builder.createTopology());

      
  } catch (AlreadyAliveException e) {  // (AlreadyAliveException ae) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Why do you not just use `StormSubmitter.submitTopology(...)`? This uploads the jar automatically in a single line. So you do not need `NimbusClient` and get much shorter code. Maybe this resolves the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown because too few config parameters are set.
I forgot to set the NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, I also changed the way the config is defined...

```
  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
  Map conf = new HashMap();
  //Map conf = Utils.readStormConfig();
  conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "100.0.0.26");
  conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT , 6627 );
  conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181 );
  conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS , 4);

  conf.put("storm.thrift.transport", "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin");
```